# Java lang Assertion Error

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I am facing this error while running my java application using Java Web Start. Although Application is running perfectly fine in eclipse and application is being loaded properly in Java web start as well. The code is trying to open a file chooser but unable to do that.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AssertionError
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getIShellFolder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.createShellFolderFromRelativePIDL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$11.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$11.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I do not know why I down voted on this question

Comment: Perhaps because you've not provided enough information for others to understand your problem and help you out with the same. Consider posting the relevant section of your code where you encounter this error

Comment: Well this is not the code error, as I said application is running perfectly fine in Eclipse and on local but Facing issue with the Java web start only and I provided hint that the code is trying to open file chooser so I don't know why that is downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So I just found the Answer to my own question. I have disabled the assertion in JNLP file and code started working perfectly fine.

I have changed

```
<j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>
```

to

```
<j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-dsa -Xnoclassgc"/>
```

Hope this will help others as well.

Comment: Of course this will help, as the `assert` is no longer executed. However, the underlying problem still exists. You simply no longer check for it

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.java.html) of that class. There are only 2 `assert` statements, and they occur both in an anonymous class. So they match perfectly with your stack trace

```
assert(isDirectory());
assert(parent != null);
```

Instead of disabling these assertions, just check why those conditions are not met and fix that.

Comment: thanks Robin, I will definitely check and let you know, thanks for looking.